# How to adapt this puppeteer docker user code so it works with pnpm and running many installed executables on the docker image?

Tags: docker, puppeteer

[Here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker) we have a user configuration for puppeteer, so you can avoid having the `--no-sandbox` flag:

```
RUN npm init -y &&  \
    npm i puppeteer \
    # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
    # same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space
    && groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /node_modules \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /package.json \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /package-lock.json
```

First of all, what is that doing? I am a frontend developer and never do anything with permissions. What does this prevent you from accessing on the system? My [docker image](https://github.com/termsurf/task/blob/make/Dockerfile) has tons of executables I need to be able to run, so not sure how to get this working with the Dockerfile I have already.

Second, how do I get this working for `pnpm`? It seems like it should just work as is, adding the `pnpm-lock.yaml` to the chown call?

If it takes a lot of changes to my docker image, what do I need to look into changing?

Comment: I'd normally recommend deleting those `chown` commands.  It's fine if the root user owns the application code, and even slightly better for security since it prevents the application from overwriting its own source code and assets.

Answer (score 0):

Those commands create a `pptruser` user and add it to a few groups. They also make this user the owner of a few directories.

To use `pnpm`:

```
RUN npm install -g pnpm

WORKDIR /home/pptruser
USER pptruser

RUN pnpm install puppeteer
```

1. Install `pnpm`.
2. Change to the `pptruser` user.
3. Change the working directory to the `pptruser` user directory.
4. Install Puppeteer as the `pptruser` user.

Steps 2 and 3 are important to ensure that Puppeteer is installed as the `pptruser` user.

Comment: What about the `groupadd` and `chown` stuff? Can you share the complete stuff I should add?

Comment: The `groupadd` command adds the `pptruser` group. The `chown` command changes the ownership of the specified folders to `pptruser` user and `pptruser` group.

Comment: Can you please be specific about what "complete stuff" you need? I believe that I have answered your original questions which were (1) explaining what's going on in your `Dockerfile` snippet and (2) how to use `pnpm` to install `puppeteer`. What else do you need?

Comment: Do I need the `chown` stuff from the original post?

Comment: Also not sure what `# same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space` means.

Comment: You probably do need the `chown` commands. I suggest that you validate that this setup is working. If so then try removing the `chown` commands. If it breaks then you need them. If not then you can safely dispense with them.

Comment: Any lines beginning with a `#` are comments. They do not do anything for the functionality of the image. They are simply there to clarify what is being done in the `Dockerfile`. The specific comment points to the fact that each `RUN` command adds a new layer to the image. The number of layers has a direct impact on the image size. So consolidating many commands into a single `RUN` command versus having numerous `RUN` commands will result in a smaller image. Generally you want your image to be as small as possible because then it will consume the least resources.

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks! (I knew about comments but not that calling commands separately added to image size).

Comment: Great. It was a pleasure to help. If you have everything that you need then please accept my answer. Thank you.